# How to make a heading for an enumeration

Tags: enumerate

I would like to do enumerations of the following form:

```
Here are some important points:
    1. Stay productive
    2. Discuss people, instead of ideas
    3. Drink lots of beer
```

However, `\begin{enumerate}` inserts a large vertical space before the start of the list. How do I cope with this? The text, that I want to be glued to the list can be either a specific mini-heading (as in the example above), or be normal paragraph, in which I want to include enumeration, but not break the body of text in more than one paragraph (i.e. no space after the enumeration as well).

By the way, here is what I am getting now:

```
Here are some important points:



    1. Stay productive
    2. Discuss people, instead of ideas
    3. Drink lots of beer
```

Comment: My advice: Use the `compactenum`environment from the `paralist`package.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I use `enumitem` currently and I don't want to switch. Is there another possibilite besides `enumitem`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `enumitem` by using `nolistsep` as the option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here are some important points:

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]%[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{enumerate}

\noindent and here are some more

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beaten for a second...

Comment: @karlkoeller I have only 30 minutes and at present I am at a old computer where taking screen shot is a pain. Have to run after 20 minutes. :)

Comment: I'll add it for you

Comment: @karlkoeller So nice of you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

Here are some important points:

\begin{compactenum}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{compactenum}


\end{document}
```

[image]